# g++ not including the directory with header files

Tags: c++, g++

This is the command I'm trying to run

```
g++ mario_game/main.cpp mario_game/game.cpp mario_game/mario.cpp dream.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_image -std=c++11 -I DreamEngine/DreamEngine2/include -o mario
```

Here's the directory structure

```
DreamEngine
└── DreamEngine2
    ├── 8bit.ttf
    ├── a.out
    ├── dream.cpp
    ├── hello.cpp
    ├── include
    │   └── dream.h
    ├── LICENSE
    └── mario_game
        ├── game.cpp
        ├── game.h
        ├── globalvars.h
        ├── main.cpp
        ├── mario.cpp
        └── mario.h
```

Any help will be appreciated. :)

I tried the comment that is said above and it says include not found.

Comment: Which header file is not found? Certainly `-I ../../../include` is not correct for any of the header files you have listed above.

Comment: What is your cwd (current working directory) when you try that command? Judging from `mario_game/main.cpp` not causing a problem which you mention it probably is `DreamEngine/DreamEngine2`.  Can you give a reason for each of the `..`?

Comment: Actually I meant to write ../DreamEngine/DreamEngine2

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `../DreamEngine/DreamEngine2` but you actually wrote `DreamEngine/DreamEngine2`.

Comment: Still don't know which header file is causing the problem. Why ask the question and not provide the most basic of information?

Comment: Ok john, I'm trying to include dream.h

Comment: n.m. i did write that actually. Didn't work